# Right way to use su and a specific command?

Tags: root, su

When I need to, I've always done things like

```
su root cmd args
```

to run `cmd` as root with `args`.  The man page used to say something about how it invoked your `cmd` using the target account's shell and `-c`, which makes sense.

On one of my newer machines, though, if I do

```
su root date
```

it complains

```
/usr/bin/date: /usr/bin/date: cannot execute binary file
```

I've discovered I can work around this by using `-c` explicitly:

```
su root -c date
```

But commands with arguments still don't work.  If I say

```
su root -c expr 1 + 2
```

it complains (that is, `expr` complains) "missing operand".  I can work around *that* by doing

```
su root -c 'expr 1 + 2'
```

It's as if the newer version of `su` is *not* automatically throwing its own `-c` in there.

Maybe I should get in the habit of always doing

```
su root -c 'command args'
```

but I'm seriously puzzled about this, because I've never had to do it that way before.

Bottom line, my questions are:

1. Did the `su` command change along the way?
2. Was I invoking it wrong all along, but older versions were more permissive?
3. What's the officially-correct way of passing a command?

(The newer version, that's acting all fussy on me, is from util-linux 2.33.1.)

[P.S. This question is specifically about `su`.  I know about `sudo`, but the circumstance that prompted this question is one for which `sudo` does not apply.]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell from looking at Git revision histories, the `util-linux` variant of the `su` utility has always required the use of the `-c` option to pass a command to execute, unless the command is a shell script.

If the command is a shell script, written for the user's login shell, `-c` is not needed.  Using `su root ./script` would be the same as logging in as root and running `$SHELL ./script` (this would override any `#!`-line in the script).

If the script is *not* written for the root user's login shell, you will want to run it as `su root -c ./script`, which would be the same as logging in as root and doing `./script` or `$SHELL -c ./script` (this would honor the script's `#!`-line).

This is also how `su` works on the non-Linux systems that I'm aware of.

---

The following is a bit of a tangent:

From the OpenBSD [`su(1)` manual](https://man.openbsd.org/su), for example:

> SYNOPSIS
>
> `su    [-fKLlm] [-a auth-type] [-c login-class] [-s login-shell] [login [shell arguments]]`
>
> [...]
>
> If the optional *shell arguments* are provided on the command line, they
> are passed to the login shell of the target login.  This allows it to
> pass arbitrary commands via the `-c` option as understood by most shells.
> Note that `-c` usually expects a single argument only; you have to quote it
> when passing multiple words.

Note that here, the `-c` option is not an option to `su`, but to the shell that `su` is invoking.  The `-c` option to `su` is separate and does something completely different on OpenBSD.  The two are distinguished by what side of the username they are located on the command line.

Since OpenBSD is just handing the root user's shell the argument after the username, you can do things like

```
$ su root -x -c 'echo hello'
Password:
+ echo hello
hello
```

(i.e., run the command with `set -x` enabled in the shell)

Since GNU command line parsing is a bit wonky (it reorders the options), this is not possible to do in exactly the same way on Linux and instead requires you to use `--` to stop option parsing:

```
$ su root -x -c 'echo hello'
su: invalid option -- 'x'
Try 'su --help' for more information.
```

(`su` interpreted both `-c` and `-x` as its own options)

```
% su root -- -x -c 'echo hello'
Password:
+ echo hello
hello
```

(`su` passes both `-c` and `-x` to the root user's shell)

Answer (score 0):

`su` is deprecated, it's only there so that you have backwards compatibly.

The new way of working:

- `sudo command arg1 arg2 ...` to run a command as root
- `sudo -u someone command arg1 arg2 ...`  to run a command as `someone`
- `sudo -i` to become root. *(You will often see people use `sudo su` for this. It will also work but can provide problems with setting the environment or `su` no longer being available in the future.)*
- `sudo -u someone -i` to become someone.

Where `su` needs the password of root, `sudo` uses your own password.
Although it may seem like this is a security problem, it's actually provides better security. See the documentation for the full info.

Most likely `sudo` is already available on your system, otherwise install it and make sure your user is in the group `sudo` in `/etc/group`

Comment: Thank you for your time in replying, but I'm afraid this is not unhelpful.  I know all about `sudo`.  My question was very specifically about `su`.

Comment: "_su is deprecated_" can you cite a reference for that please? I've just had a quick look around and can't find any evidence for this claim. Thanks

Comment: Tiny correction: `su` is considered, although not official, deprecated. Most trivial piece of "evidence": Systems with a root password are extremely rare nowadays. This makes `su` completely useless.